# Would you accept this proof for $(A^c)^c = A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

In my exercises I had the following question:

Prove that $(A^c)^c = A$.

My solution:

Let $A$ be a set where $A\subset X$. $A = \{x \in X, x \in A\}$ by definition.

$A^c = \{x \in X, x \notin A\}$

Let $P(x)$ be the proposition that $x \in X$ and $Q(x)$ be the proposition that $x \in A$. Therefore:

$A = P(x) \wedge  Q(x)$

$A^c = P(x) \wedge ¬Q(x)$

$(A^c)^c = P(x) \wedge ¬(P(x) \wedge ¬Q(x)) \iff P(x) \wedge (¬P(x) \vee Q(x)) \iff (P(x) \wedge ¬P(x)) \vee (P(x) \wedge Q(x)) \iff False \vee (P(x) \wedge Q(x)) \iff P(x) \wedge Q(x) = A$

Hence, $(A^c)^c = A$.

Is this a solid enough proof, or should I do a different approach?

Note: My actual written work contains references to De Morgan's Laws, and other propositions in the course that allow me to do the logical equivalences.

Comment: "$\;A=x\in X\;$ "?? This doesn't make much sense, nor does the continuation.

Comment: I agree, it seems a bit odd, but I put it in there to make clear the relation between $P(x) \wedge Q(x)$ being A. How should I express that bit?

Comment: Apart from you omitting the $\{ \}$, apart from saying $A = P(x) \wedge  Q(x)$ and apart from writing $A^c = P(x) \wedge ¬Q(x)$, it's fine. You obviously got the right idea.

Comment: No, it is not odd, @J_mie6: it simply makes no sense.

Comment: @Timbuc Ah I see, it makes no sense without the braces, with the braces it just seems odd.

Comment: I'm not sure what braces are you referring to, @J_mie6 .Oh, I see now. Yes, that's right now

Comment: The statement $A=P(x)\wedge Q(x)$ makes no sense. One is a set, the other is a statement. I'm guessing you mean that the statements $x\in A$ and $P(x)\wedge Q(x)$ are equivalent. It's almost always better to express yourself with words instead of symbols.

Comment: I  think your proof is correct now, though pretty odd...and strangely pretty, using logic theory stuff. +1

Comment: @Samuel, I think that statement makes sense...without being too strict with the formal requirements.

Comment: As it turns out the next question can be done in the exact same way, albeit with different propositions. So it might just be worth my while to define the logic bit first as an identity and then invoke it for both parts, with their respective propositions :). Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I have to agree with Samuel's comment here: writing $A = P(x)\wedge Q(x)$ isn't a logical statement.  You want, at least, $A=\{x: P(x)\wedge Q(x)\}$ or some form of comprehension to get rid of that 'free' $x$ on the right.  Also, using your operations, you haven't shown how to _derive_ $A^c$ from $A$ and so you haven't strictly proven the first expression for $(A^c)^c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not directly by the definition? It is extremely simple:

$$x\in A\iff x\notin A^c\iff x\in(A^c)^c$$

Comment: This is how I would have got about it if I hadn't convinced myself otherwise that it isn't what they are looking for, given that we proved that $A \cup (B \cup C) \iff (A \cup B) \cup C$ earlier today using propositions. I assumed the same sort of system was expected